# background worker and threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker, vb.net-2010

i am using a background worker with a timer to call a function that has a for loop... as below :

```
 Private Sub t_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles t.Tick
        t.Enabled = False
        t.Interval = 5000
        Start()
End Sub

 Sub Start()
    If frm10BckWorker.IsBusy <> True Then
        frm10BckWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        frm10BckWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub frm2BckWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles frm10BckWorker.DoWork
    StartSending()
End Sub

 Sub StartSending()
    Try
        f.GetNumbers("JK_SP_GET_Users_TO_PROCEED", UsersBulkCnx(8))

        count = f.numbersTable.Rows.Count
        If count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        For I = 0 To count - 1

            Id = Trim(f.GetReaderValue(f.numbersTable.Rows(I).Item("ID")))
            MO = Trim(f.GetReaderValue(f.numbersTable.Rows(I).Item("MO")))
            FamilyName = Trim(f.GetReaderValue(f.numbersTable.Rows(I).Item("FamilyName")))
            CName = Trim(f.GetReaderValue(f.numbersTable.Rows(I).Item("ContactNAme")))
            ImageUrl = Trim(f.GetReaderValue(f.numbersTable.Rows(I).Item("ImageUrl")))

            If Not f.InsertUsers(MO, FamilyName, CName,UsersCnx(8)) Then
                PROC = -1
            End If

            f.DeleteBulk(Id, BulkNbrCnx(8))
            f.InsertHistory(MO, FamilyName, CName,ImageUrl, UsersBulkCnx(8))

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        f.WriteToText("StartSending", ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

what i need is to run in background this function `f.InsertHistory` that i call in the for loop and keep the loop running at the time without waiting for this function to end to go to the next record in the loop,

any suggestions please?

Comment: So you want it to move on to the next iteration of the loop without waiting for f.inserthistory to finish?  In that case, you'd need each iteration of the loop to be in its own backgroundworker or thread.  Basically, you'll want to instantiate a backgroundworker inside the loop. That's going to get messy.  You could define some sort of object that declares a backgroundworker and runs f.InsertHistory and then just instantiate a new instance of that object in the loop each time.  That would be a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom how can i call the `dowork` event for every background worker generated in the for loop?